# Ruby-on-Rails how to show exceptions caught by AbstractController::ActionNotFound?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I've got a webapp running on Ruby (1.8.7) & Rails (3.0.0).

I've noticed several times now that `AbstractController::ActionNotFound` errors are logged and 404 responses returned, when the underlying issue is not really due to the action not being *found*, per se (that seems to imply to me that you simply haven't defined the route for an action).

So my question is, how can one tell rails to log the originating exception instead of consuming it and spitting out a generically unhelpful message? From searching around on forums, it seems like this bland error message is the source of a lot of frustration.

For instance, a recent error:

> AbstractController::ActionNotFound (The action 'upload_image' could not be found for DealsController)

Which was actually being caused by this (I had used javascript to create a form in the DOM instead of writing an erb with the rails form_tag, which of course was failing Rails' built-in CSRF token validation):

> ActionController::InvalidAuthenticityToken (ActionController::InvalidAuthenticityToken)

Please note that this is just an example of what sort of problems "ActionNotFound" can mask. I'm not interested in solving this particular problem (solved), but really the general case of how to show more salient error messages instead of ActionNotFound.

Thanks!

Comment: In development mode, no errors should be suppressed at all. Are you doing something strange to cause those errors to not even be shown in development?

Comment: I don't *think* I'm doing anything strange, but then again I recently jumped in to this application, so not totally familiar with the config. One thought, perhaps Rails is not raising exceptions at all at this layer, but rather flowing a particular class of "errors" into ActionNotFound? I wish I could say more, but I'm fairly new to Ruby and certainly unfamiliar with Rails source code.

Comment: For reference, here is where ActionNotFound is being raised in the source. Starting to dig a little further into this. https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/v3.0.0/actionpack/lib/abstract_controller/base.rb

Comment: first of all Rails 3 is not compatible with Ruby less than 1.8.7

Comment: authenticity token checks every requests except GET by special token uniq per user session.

Comment: Typo, I'm running 1.8.7, not 1.8.5. Edited question.